# Android fragment transition happens after app enters background

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have a registration activity, inside which I have multiple fragments (step-by-step registration flow)..

In the activity, I have this updateRegistrationStage() method that handles fragment transition.. here is the problem:
1) I click continue button, submit some data to server and waiting for response..
2) Before I get any response, I press home button so app enters background..
3) then, I got the response and supposed to jump to next fragment... at this point, I call:

```
transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.registration_container, newFragment, newFragment.toString());
transaction.commit();
```

And app crashes.. throwing

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

if I change last line to

```
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

It would say

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
```

I think it's possible to set a flag e.g. isActivityAlive to make sure transaction commit when activity is still alive... but.. that's pretty ugly. Is there a better way of cancelling fragment transaction when the activity is no longer active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store state of registration seperate from UI and use listeners for update UI. use activity callback `onStart` for updating state and initializing all listeners and `onStop` for disposing listeners

UPDATE: i wrote a simple stub for this solution, but i didn't try compile. It's for example only

```
//UI
public class RCMActivity extends Activity {

    RegistrationManager registrationManager = RegistrationManager.getInstance();
    OnRegistrationListener listener = new OnRegistrationListener() {
        public void onComplete(State state) {
            //change UI here
        }
        public void onFailed() {}
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        registrationManager.setListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStart();
        registrationManager.setListener(null);
    }
}

//state in separate file
public class RegistrationManager {
    enum State {IDLE, FIRST_STEP, SECOND_STEP, THIRD_STEP};
    public interface OnRegistrationListener {
        void onComplete(State state);
        void onFailded();
    }

    private OnRegistrationListener listener;

    private State state = IDLE;

    public void setOnRegistrationListener(OnRegistrationListener l)
    {
        listener = l;
    }

    public static RegistrationManager getInstance() {//for example it's singleton}
}
```

Comment: can you give me some more details? what should be the right flow/structure.. example?